# Authentication Issue Using PostgreSQL dblink

Tags: postgresql, authentication, dblink

How do you create a dblink connection in Postgres without supplying username & password (for security reasons)?

Running the following query returns this error:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('conn_1','dbname=adatabase');

"could not establish connection 08001"
```

My pgpass.conf file has the following entry and I'm running the script as the postgres user in pgAdmin:

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:apassword
```

Using **dblink_connect_u** also returns the same error.

I'm running Postgres 9.2 on Windows 2012 Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're connecting to a PostgreSQL database, you can modify [your pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) on the server you're connecting to so that (for example) passwordless connections are allowed for your user from the local machine:

```
local   all   youruser                  trust
host    all   youruser   127.0.0.1/32   trust
host    all   youruser   ::1/128        trust
```

Ideally, you would create a PostgreSQL user on the server specifically for dblink, and grant only the necessary rights (only `SELECT` on specific tables, for example).

Comment: Adding the IPv6 trust line to pg_hba.conf did the trick, although I'm not sure why.  I'm running the test script on the server itself (i.e. client and server are the same machine), which may explain it.

Answer (score 1):

The server uses its own pgpass file, not "yours" which is inaccessible to it.

Consider this excerpt from [`dblink_connect_u`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-connect-u.html) documentation:

> Also, even if the remote server does demand a password, it is possible
>   for the password to be supplied from the server environment, such as a
>   ~/.pgpass file **belonging to the server's user**.

In unix it would be `~postgres/.pgpass`, in Windows you should find the equivalent location depending on the OS user running the server's processes (either `postgres` or a system account, depending on your installer).

In case the OS user doesn't have a home directory or it's not sensible to put `pgpass.conf` in there, you may set a different location through the [`PGPASSFILE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) environment variable. I can't tell how a Windows administrator sets an environment variable for a specific service, though.

Comment: A good point to remember. I should have mentioned I'm running the test script from the server itself!